# What is the most efficient way to get new executables whitelisted at the big antivirus companies?

Tags: windows, certificate, anti-virus, code-signing, certificate-authority

## The problem explained

We developed an application (see https://embeetle.com). To avoid false positives, all our executables and dll's are code-signed with an Extended Verification Code Signing Certificate from Sectigo. Despite this, our users complain that Norton flags and deletes our executables and dll's immediately when they try to launch the software:

[image]

As you can see, the threat is based on the fact that our software is "very new" and has "fewer than 5 users in the Norton Community". It is categorized as a WS.Reputation.1 threat (see https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/191764/endpoint-protection-detects-known-good-a.html):

> When using Symantec Endpoint Protection (SEP), the SEP client may log WS.Reputation.1 detections on legitimate executable files or installers from trusted vendors. Depending on policy settings, these files may be Quarantined or deleted.

> The WS.Reputation1 detection indicates a suspicious file and not a traditional anti-virus/malware detection. This SEP detection is from the Insight (File Reputation) feature of the SEP client. This detection conveys that the file's global reputation within the larger Broadcom community is not yet trusted based on information such as age, hash, and number of times seen.

> The most common cause of this is a change to the file, such as a new version of an application. When the new application version is deployed to a SEP endpoint, SEP client will look up the file from the Broadcom Insight database. If the file is too new or doesn't have enough usage to determine if the file is trustworthy, the SEP client returns a detection of WS.Reputation1. However, this does not indicate that the file is a threat, only that it is not trusted based on the prevalence in the larger Broadcom community based on usage, age, and other factors.

Unfortunately, our executables and dlls are very vulnerable to this:

- As a young software company, we still have a small userbase.
- We push out updates very regularly (sometimes once a week). Such an update means: new executables and dll's.

## Solution 1: whitelisting executables

The solution most people present is to submit the executables and dlls as False Positives to the antivirus companies. These companies typically have online submission forms. Unfortunately, this is not a sustainable solution:

- Our software consists of many executables and dlls interacting with each other. Submitting them one-by-one in online forms would take many hours, especially if we'd have to do it for all the big antivirus vendors.
- We push out new executables and dlls at every update. This means we'd have to repeat the online submissions everytime.
- How long do these online submission forms take to be completely processed? If we push out a new update (eg. for an important bugfix), we don't want to wait for months.

## Solution 2: whitelisting our Code Signing Certificate

If we can get our Code Signing Certificate to be trusted by the big antivirus vendors, our business is saved. I've read that big software corporations already practice this. The executables and dlls they release are automatically trusted by the Antivirus companies.

Large corporations can achieve this - how can a small software business like ours achieve it too?

## Solution 3: Fight Norton

Out of sheer desperation, I've started a petition:

[image]

https://www.change.org/norton-antivirus
Hopefully Norton will see it and stop this practice that hurts small software developers like us.

Comment: "How long do these online submission forms take to be completely processed?" - Only Norton can answer this particular question. Your file is being flagged based on reputation not due the fact it is or isn't signed.  You would have to reach out to Norton to determine the reason, their behavioral scanner, is picking up your executable as a threat.

Comment: https://community.norton.com/en/forums/startup-software-company-how-do-we-get-our-executables-whitelisted Use virustotal.com, then complain when false positives occur? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/intelligence/criteria?view=o365-worldwide
& https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2018/08/16/partnering-with-the-industry-to-minimize-false-positives/

Comment: Hi @Gantendo, the link you posted to the Norton forum is an old post from me. Back then, our executables were not yet signed. Now they're signed with an EV Code Signing Certificate from Sectigo.

Comment: @Gantendo, the VirusTotal Monitor tool, to proactively submit executables for whitelisting (if I understood the service correctly) no longer exists. VirusTotal only has an API to check if an executable triggers one or more antivirus engines.

Comment: @Ramhound, our files are flagged based on the fact that they are "very new" and "unknown to the Norton Community". Please read the Broadcom page I linked to. You'll see this is a very common situation, especially right after an update. - Our files are not flagged based on their behavior. It's only because they're new. See: https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/191764/endpoint-protection-detects-known-good-a.html

Comment: Have you instructed your clients to do the following "Add the digital signature of the file(s) to the Exceptions Policy"? By adding the certificate itself, it should whitelist, any files signed by the certificate.   Without specifics about the certificate, difficult to tell, if it's fine and this is a problem with Norton or the certificate is to blame.